# Check for last button tap

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I'm using an `AVPlayer` and when I click the forward button to go to the next song it automatically downloads the song As expected. But if I click the forward button many many many times the app gets very laggy. So is there a way to call the function of the forward button if it isn't tapped for example for Two seconds?
I'm using Xcode 10 with Swift 4.2 and Firebase for downloading the URL and passing it in the `AVPlayer` with `AVPlayerItem(url: url)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
var timer: Timer!
```

in Button action:

```
if let timer = timer {
   timer.invalidate()
}
timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.5, target: self, selector: #selector(play), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)


@objc func play() {
    self.play()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could capture the time and implement your code. Try this code:

```
var lastTap:Date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 0)

func buttonTapped(sender:Any) {
    // Checks if it has been tapped in the last two seconds
    if (Date().timeIntervalSince(lastTap) < 2) {
        return
    }
    lastTap = Date()

    // Perform playing
    playSong()
}
```